# How do I save image produced by asciiview?

Tags: bash, command-line, ascii, ascii-art

When I run command asciiview image.jpg I'm able to view image in the terminal and quit browser using <kbd>q</kbd> key. I've tried different ways to redirect the output of the `asciiview image.jpg` to the console output (stdout) or save in the file such as `asciiview image.jpg > ascii_art.txt` or `asciiview -driver stdout image.jpg > ascii_art.txt` but I didn't get a result as I'm expecting. In the first case, I had to manually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get a proper image in the text file, in the second case I didn't get anything meaningful that would resemble the picture. Have anyone ideas how I can save image produced by asciiview directly to file or display it in the console output without entering browser and having to press <kbd>q</kbd> key?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `echo q | asciiview` ??  That seems to be how [others](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImageMode) have handled embedding `asciiview` in their process.

> ```sh
> echo q | asciiview -driver stdout -kbddriver stdin %s 2>/dev/null
> ```

The `-kbddriver stdin` also looks important here.  Throwing errors into `/dev/null` is also worth considering.

Comment: When I set `driver stdout` the result isn't the same quality as ASCII art produced by the same `asciiview %s` command.

Example:
- image produced by command `asciiview %s`: https://imgur.com/a/IGeeLxi,
- image produced by command `echo q | asciiview -driver stdout -kbddriver stdin %s 2>/dev/null`: https://imgur.com/a/aqCQvhs

Comment: Playing with your terminal width might help.  Further investigation would require digging into the source code.  http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/ has links to the sources and mentions some other packages, like gimp, that supposedly have interoperability with with asciiview.

Comment: Does exist any simpler way to achieve it? I tried other programs such as jp2a or img2txt but asciiview gives me the best results.

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Comment: @polemon It was quoted because that code came from https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImageMode (which was linked in the answer).

Comment: Well, then let's put it in a quotation block then, but I think removing the actual `"` makes it a little clearer...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the s key... I suppose that's similar to the q key process.

- go to the output file
- hit the 's' key on the keyboard.
- Follow the prompts for type, width etc.
- Save requires a Y (not just the default way... if you know what I mean) ;)

Works better with pnm - export original image to pnm format for best results.

[image]